# DocumentDb Identity Provider for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to provide authorization to the user, using DocumentDb at the backend - But I am unable to find any resources regarding the same.  The documentation provided is for SQL based ones (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html).

Any help?

Comment: I have a Project that uses the same, just check it out https://github.com/arunselvakumar/jericho

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To provide you with a starting point, there are several important issues to bear in mind when looking at using Identity with *ASP.Net Core*:

**Framework Compatibility**

You mention that you will be using *ASP.Net Core*, and this can be used with either .Net Core, or the 'full' .Net Framework (e.g. .Net Framework 4.5.1), which can be specified in your `project.json` under the `frameworks` property.

The Microsoft DocumentDB native .Net client does **not** support .Net Core; so, you must configure ASP.Net Core to target the 'full' .Net Framework. If you are unsure how to do this, you can create a new project in Visual Studio 2015, and select the 'ASP.Net Core (.Net Framework)' Project Template; the `project.json` will have its `framework` property correctly configured for you.

**'Identity' Version**

There are several versions of ASP.Net Identity; be aware when selecting a provider, that most currently reference ASP.Net Identity **2.2.1**; however, the latest version is **3**, released alongside *ASP.Net Core*, supported by the NuGet package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/), which has some differences and additional features. (Note that you can use this latter package with the full .Net Framework.)

**No Official Implementation**

Microsoft has decided not to create an official DocumentDB implementation for ASP.Net Identity, citing that 'there are two community projects available' (reference [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6349216-provider-for-asp-net-identity))

**Third-Party Support**

Of the available third-party implementations, [this one](https://github.com/tracker086/DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity) by Adrian Fernandez is the most widely used that provides support for ASP.Net Identity **3** using the Microsoft native DocumentDB client. Samples are included in the GitHub repository. (***Please see update below.***)

**Example Usage**

An example of using this DocumentDB provider with ASP.Net, including additional features, can be found [here](http://www.nosqlcentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/5-documentdb-golf-tracker-article-a-word-on-identity).

An additional example of using ASP.Net Core with the Microsoft DocumentDB provider can be found [here](http://dotnetthoughts.net/using-azure-document-db-in-aspnet-core/).

*I have written my own Identity 3 provider for DocumentDB; if I release this on GitHub I will update this answer with a link.*

**UPDATE 19/04/2017**

For those looking for a solution, I now recommend the [AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb](https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb) project by **Bernhard Koenig**. It is feature-complete, includes Unit Tests, and a sample ASP.Net Core project. Also available via Nuget. It supports `netstandard1.6` an `net46` profiles.

Comment: Thank a lot for the detailed response bro, helped a lot :-)

Comment: Please release your Identity 3 provider. :-)

Comment: @Holf Unfortunately I am unable to do so as it is part of a commercial product. I have, however, updated my answer to include a link to what I currently consider to be the most complete open-source project, which I would recommend.

Comment: this AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb  is just what i need, thx for the info!

Answer (score 1):

my understanding is the Microsoft made it possible to use Mongo drivers with DocumentDb so maybe you could use this [Mongo implementation for asp.net core identity](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB)

or google further for existing work that others may have done in this direction.

To implement it yourself you would need to implement at minimum [IUserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IUserStore.cs) and [IRoleStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IRoleStore.cs) you can also refer to the EF implementations [UserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs) and [RoleStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/RoleStore.cs) for inspiration and guidance on implementing those.

Comment: As an FYI, the project linked is specific to ASP.Net Identity version 2.2.1, which is not the latest. Just like DocumentDB clients, MongoDB clients are also incompatible with .Net *Core* (it can be used with ASP.Net Core on *.Net Framework*). I have expanded some information on this in another answer. There might also be some confusion here about 'Core'. The project mentioned references 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core' version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45"; it is nothing to do with ASP.Net Core.

Comment: yeah, my bad on that it said the "new" ASP.NET Identity, I didn't look at it closely, I just updated the link in my answer to point to this one which is for .NET Core https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB

Comment: no problem, this Core label is heavily misused and causes confusion. I wouldn't personally go down the route of trying to use a MongoDB implementation, when there is already a DocumentDB one, that also supports the Role provider (link in my answer). The MongoDB driver compatibility is focussed on assisting people in migrating existing MongoDB based apps to DocumentDB, **not** as a replacement for the native DocumentDB client, which is very heavily optimised (and this is the reason it is not yet ported to .Net Core - it needs Framework features).

Comment: agreed, if there is a working one for DocumentDb that is the way to go, your answer is better than mine

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be using a DocumentDB provider for the .NET Core Identity framework. But there were none so far which is why I created [AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB](https://github.com/FelschR/aspnet-identity-documentdb) and decided to publish it on GitHub under the MIT license.

It is a port of an existing mongodb provider for .NET Core Identity and stores Claims, Tokens & Logins as nested objects. Although one could use DocumentDB with a mongodb interface it's recommended to use the native SDK if possible.

The library is already quite stable and available as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB) package.

**Notice:**
The DocumentDB SDK for C# itself does not support .NET Core as a target platform in the stable release. **Fortunately** Microsoft is already working on adding .NET Core support and published a preview of the DocumentDB SDK with :NET Standard support at the Connect(); 2016 event.
[AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB](https://github.com/FelschR/aspnet-identity-documentdb) supports both SDKs.

.NET Standard is a specification of APIs that should be available on all .NET runtimes and is currently supported by .NET Core and .NET Framework.